# HTML tables with jQuery pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, html-table

I am trying to create a table such that when there are more than 10 rows I want to create a hyperlink which tells the user to go on the next page. The concept is called pagination, but how can I achieve it with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)/ [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Table</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            th {
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
            th td {
                 border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>Heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr><td>This is td</td><td>This is td</td></tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a server-side language?

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively to the plugin, if you want to see simplified code so you can educate yourself as to how pagination works, have a look at this fiddle I knocked up for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/29W9Q/

The code simply binds two buttons, previous and next to change the visibility of the rows of the table that you specified.  Each time a button is clicked, the steps are: see if you can move backward or forward, hide the current rows, find the rows that should be visible, 10 up or 10 down, and then make them visible.  The rest of the code is to illustrate the example.

The real jQuery work is being done by the [less-than](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [greater-than](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors: `:lt()` and `:gt()`, to select the rows for hiding/showing.

```
var maxRows = 10;
$('.paginated-table').each(function() {
    var cTable = $(this);
    var cRows = cTable.find('tr:gt(0)');
    var cRowCount = cRows.size();

    if (cRowCount < maxRows) {
        return;
    }

    /* add numbers to the rows for visuals on the demo */
    cRows.each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('td:first').text(function(j, val) {
           return (i + 1) + " - " + val;
        }); 
    });

    /* hide all rows above the max initially */
    cRows.filter(':gt(' + (maxRows - 1) + ')').hide();

    var cPrev = cTable.siblings('.prev');
    var cNext = cTable.siblings('.next');

    /* start with previous disabled */
    cPrev.addClass('disabled');

    cPrev.click(function() {
        var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

        if (cPrev.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }

        cRows.hide();
        if (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1 > 0) {
            cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible - maxRows - 1) + ')').show();
        } else {
            cRows.filter(':lt(' + cFirstVisible + ')').show();
        }

        if (cFirstVisible - maxRows <= 0) {
            cPrev.addClass('disabled');
        }

        cNext.removeClass('disabled');

        return false;
    });

    cNext.click(function() {
        var cFirstVisible = cRows.index(cRows.filter(':visible'));

        if (cNext.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }

        cRows.hide();
        cRows.filter(':lt(' + (cFirstVisible +2 * maxRows) + '):gt(' + (cFirstVisible + maxRows - 1) + ')').show();

        if (cFirstVisible + 2 * maxRows >= cRows.size()) {
            cNext.addClass('disabled');
        }

        cPrev.removeClass('disabled');

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: +1 that is very helpful. I hate using plugins unless absolutely necessary because I like to have full customize-ability of the code and not have to work with the code they made.

Comment: @chromedude Agreed, although reinventing the wheel is "bad" - it helps to know exactly what is going on in case you need to change it subtly.  Clients are not keen on the answer "it doesn't do that" coming from their developers.  jQuery (and the draggable/droppable UI classes) are about the only JS libraries I use.

Comment: how about having like (<< 1 2 3 >>)  is there someone can do that? :) thanks.

Comment: @user2789695: Whilst directly related, that's a large expansion on what is there, as it's not the most easy thing to bolt on to this example.  There are almost certainly other answers demonstrating this on the site.